# Enhanced Lookup for Contract on Quote in CPQ

Tags: quote, cpq, contracts

In CPQ Quote object record when we try to add Master Contract Record using lookup Icon we only see Contract Number and Owner.
[image]
We wanted to enhanced this lookup to be able search it by Contract Name , we wanted to check if there is any out of box feature available to achieve this.
 Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the below helps:

1.Check whether the Contract Name is selected in lookup Dialogues of Contract Search Layout.

2.For Contract Name field,as per the default settings,field level access is hidden. Enable it(Make it visible)for the required profile.

Comment: Thanks I misjudged it , FLS was a problem , I can only Laugh now.